# How can I determine the behavior of a certain inequality?

Tags: inequalities

Consider the expression

$\qquad 2(1-2c)/(c-1)^2$

where $c < 0$.

I would like to know if it is bigger than 1 anywhere in its domain.

```
2(1-2c)/(c-1)^2
```

Comment: If you evaluate `Reduce[{2 (1 - 2 c) / (c - 1)^2 > 1, c < 0}]`, you will see that your expression is larger than 1 only in a certain range of negative values of $c$.

Answer (score 3):

The function range of your expression (let's say, $y$) is $0 < y < 2$, which can be shown by

```
FunctionRange[{2 (1 - 2 c) / (c - 1)^2, c < 0}, c, y]
```

To get the point where $y = 1$,

```
Solve[2 (1 - 2 c) / (c - 1)^2 == 1 && c < 0, c]
```

For completeness: as already MarcoB mentioned in his comment, you can get the range where $y > 1$ (or $y < 1$) by `Reduce`:

```
Reduce[2 (1 - 2 c) / (c - 1)^2 > 1 && c < 0]
```

```
Reduce[2 (1 - 2 c) / (c - 1)^2 < 1 && c < 0]
```